# going through ID's in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make a script that goes through several elements. I've come up with the idea to give the `HTML elements` a numeric `id` value. `id=0` and I use the following jquery for to access it.

```
var image_id = 0;//initializing the image id variable 
var get_image = document.getElementById(image_id);//getting the element based on the ID
var image = $(get_image);//creating a selector

function doSomething()
{
    image_id++;
}
//finally I use this line of code to display the number on screen to check it's value
$("span").text(image_id);
doSomething()
```

the code above does work properly as I want it to except for the `image_id++` line...in a way. When I place an `alert` underneath it it does show me the value is increased however it;s not applied. the value displayed on the `span`element  is always 0 the affected element is also not effected by the code. Could anyone point me out what I'm doing wrong or if it's at all possible or suggest a more effective method I appreciate all feedback

Comment: Where, and how, are you calling the function?

Comment: only numeric id to html element should avoided

Comment: The proper selector for `id=0` would be `'#0'`...

Comment: you cannot add a numeic value as a `id` value.

Comment: right I forgot that part the function is being called in the jquery itself I'll edit the code right now

Comment: Just mark the elements with a class, and use `$('.class').each(function(){...});`

Comment: @thecodeparadox - Right, technically numeric ID's are not allowed by the spec. They still work, though. A better solution would be to use an alphanumeric prefix: `id="img-01"` or a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$('img').each(function(i,v){
   var id  = $(this).attr('id')
   $('span').text(id); // or $('span').text($('span').text() + " " + id)
})
```